# Is there a piece of software that can scramble/blur part of an audio file automatically?

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, scramble

This is my second question ever posted on here, so please let me know if I have done something wrong.

I am faced with an interesting issue today. I work for a call center and one of the clients my company verifies information for wants to gather bank account numbers from customers and wants our customer service agents to enter said bank account numbers into the clients external website.

These bank account numbers are not going to be saved anywhere on our local databases, but the audio in which our CSRs are gathering the bank account numbers will be saved in our system. The plain text will not be available but the sound files will. My question is if there is a way to automatically scramble a certain part of a recording automatically using a program? I know this is a serious shot in the dark. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Justin, this site is mostly about programming questions, your one is not really about programming since you haven't wrote any program yet. You could probably ask this question in some other place, like it could be a good fit for Quora. To answer your question, yes, it is pretty trivial task to cut a chunk of recording, you do not need to blur it, you can make it a complete silence.

Comment: Thank you Nikolay. I'll post this question elsewhere for specifics. I appreciate the response. Have a good one!

Comment: I am working on something similar and has provided a response to OP question. Please check answer

Answer (score 4):

While your question does not ask for specific programming related issue, I will try to answer it since i am working on something similar.

Can we automatically scramble a certain part of a recording automatically using a program?
We certainly can. It will depend upon how much complex you would like to make it.

While there are complex method, from a very basic concept perspective, we will need to take the recorded audio file and process in following stages.

1. Split words in audio file : This will need silence recognition
   between the words.
2. Pass each word through an speech recognition system
3. Come up with a method to scramble. Do you want to silence , 
   `jumble` , fill it with `white noise` or `encode`.
4. Compare recognized word against the word you want to `scramble` ,
   if there is a match `scramble` based upon chosen method
5. Combine (`concatenate`) all the words in proper sequence and store
   it.

I've put together a basic prototype that will do above except (4). 
The program heavily utilizes [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) , which provides easier ways to manipulate audio. A tutorial on that can be found [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown).

The program basically,

1) I downloaded open-source  pre-recorded wav file [from this site](https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/index.jsp) for numbers `0` to `10` and concatenated them using `pydub`.
The program slices given audio file in chunks of one second. I've used [audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) to separate each word so that they fit within one second window. In real life, that will not be the case.

2) It then passes the word through [google speech recognition engine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/2.1.3) and shows the recognized word. As you will see the word `six` is not recognized properly. You will need a robust `speech recognition engine` for this purpose.

3) The program offers three different `scramble` method.

- a) Reverse the word
- b) Replace word with equivalent `white noise`
- c) Replace word with `silence`

4) It  then choose three words `9` , `4` and `2` and apply above `scramble` method and replace the corresponding word file

5)It then concatenates all the words along-with scrambled words in proper order and create output file.

Note: I didn't have enough time to add comparison between word to scramble and recognized word.

Let me know if there are any questions.

****Demo Code:****

```
""" Declarations """ 
import speech_recognition as sr
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence
from pydub.generators import WhiteNoise
from pydub.playback import play



""" Function for Speech Recognition """ 
def processAudio(WAV_FILE):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.WavFile(WAV_FILE) as source:
        audio = r.record(source) # read the entire WAV file

    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
    try:  
        print("recognizedWord=" + r.recognize_google(audio))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from GSR; {0}".format(e))

""" Function to scramble word based upon choice """ 
def scramble_audio(aWord, option):
    scramble_file = export_path + "slice" + str(aWord) +".wav"
    scramble_audioseg = AudioSegment.from_wav(scramble_file)    
    aWord_length = scramble_audioseg.__len__() #Get length of word segment to scramble

    if option == "reverse":     #Reverse word to scramble
        scrambled_word = scramble_audioseg.reverse()        

    elif option == "whiteNoise":    #Replace word to scramble with white noise     
        wn = WhiteNoise()           #Instantiate White Noise Object         
        aWord_length = scramble_audioseg.__len__()              #Get length of word segment
        scrambled_word = wn.to_audio_segment(duration=aWord_length) #Create audio_segment

    elif option == "silence":               #Replace word to scramble with silence
        scrambled_word =  AudioSegment.silent(duration=aWord_length) 

    print ("Scrambling and Exporting %s" % scramble_file)
    scrambled_word.export(scramble_file, format="wav") #Export merged audio file


if __name__ == "__main__":

    export_path = ".//splitAudio//"
    in_audio_file = "0-10.wav"
    out_audio_file = export_path + "scrambledAudio.wav"

    #Read main audio file to be processed. Assuming in the same folder as this script
    sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(in_audio_file)

    sec2_splice = 1  #Splice threshold in sec

    audio_length = len(sound) # Total Audio Length In millisec

    q, r = divmod(audio_length, sec2_splice) #Get quotient and remainder 

    #Get total segments and rounds to next greater integer 
    total_segments=  (q + int(bool(r)) ) / 1000  #Converting to sec

    #Iterate through slices every one second and export
    print ("")
    n=0
    while n <= total_segments:
        print ("Making slice  from %d to %d  (sec)" % (n , sec2_splice ))    
        temp_object = sound[ (n * 1000) : (sec2_splice * 1000)] #Slicing is done in millisec
        myaudio_file = export_path + "slice" + str(n) +".wav"
        temp_object.export(myaudio_file , format="wav") 
        print ("Trying to recognize %d " %n)
        processAudio(myaudio_file)   
        n = sec2_splice
        sec2_splice += 1    


    #Scramble desired audio slice
    print ("")
    scramble_word = 9
    scramble_audio(scramble_word, "reverse" )

    scramble_word = 4
    scramble_audio(scramble_word, "whiteNoise" )

    scramble_word = 2
    scramble_audio(scramble_word, "silence" )
    #Combine modified audio

    final_audio = AudioSegment.empty()  #Create empty  AudioSegment
    print ("")
    i = 0
    while i <= total_segments:
        temp_audio_file = export_path + "slice" + str(i) +".wav"
        temp_audio_seg = AudioSegment.from_wav(temp_audio_file)
        print ("Combining %s"  % temp_audio_file )
        final_audio = final_audio.append(temp_audio_seg, crossfade=0)
        i += 1

    print ("Exporting final audio %s"  % out_audio_file )
    final_audio.export(out_audio_file , format="wav")
```

**Output:**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 

Making slice  from 0 to 1  (sec)
Trying to recognize 0 
recognizedWord=0
Making slice  from 1 to 2  (sec)
Trying to recognize 1 
recognizedWord=1
Making slice  from 2 to 3  (sec)
Trying to recognize 2 
Could not understand audio
Making slice  from 3 to 4  (sec)
Trying to recognize 3 
recognizedWord=3
Making slice  from 4 to 5  (sec)
Trying to recognize 4 
recognizedWord=4
Making slice  from 5 to 6  (sec)
Trying to recognize 5 
recognizedWord=5
Making slice  from 6 to 7  (sec)
Trying to recognize 6 
recognizedWord=sex
Making slice  from 7 to 8  (sec)
Trying to recognize 7 
recognizedWord=7
Making slice  from 8 to 9  (sec)
Trying to recognize 8 
recognizedWord=8
Making slice  from 9 to 10  (sec)
Trying to recognize 9 
recognizedWord=9
Making slice  from 10 to 11  (sec)
Trying to recognize 10 
recognizedWord=10

Scrambling and Exporting .//splitAudio//slice9.wav
Scrambling and Exporting .//splitAudio//slice4.wav
Scrambling and Exporting .//splitAudio//slice2.wav

Combining .//splitAudio//slice0.wav
Combining .//splitAudio//slice1.wav
Combining .//splitAudio//slice2.wav
Combining .//splitAudio//slice3.wav
Combining .//splitAudio//slice4.wav
Combining .//splitAudio//slice5.wav
Combining .//splitAudio//slice6.wav
Combining .//splitAudio//slice7.wav
Combining .//splitAudio//slice8.wav
Combining .//splitAudio//slice9.wav
Combining .//splitAudio//slice10.wav
Exporting final audio .//splitAudio//scrambledAudio.wav
>>>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for posting this. I will forward this to someone in my dev team who is more suited to look this over than I. I appreciate the response!

Comment: Hi- does this answer your question? if yes do accept the answer [check mark near vote ] or let me know if you need any clarifications.